# How do I remove these electrical connectors on the inside of my drivers side door?

Tags: electrical, mazda, door

I have a 2004 Mazda B2300.

I am pretty green at anything electrical or automotive for that matter and was trying to replace my door handle that broke off. I have almost removed the whole inner panel, but I don't know how to remove these electrical connectors.

Do I need to unplug anything prior to doing this?

[image: terminals I want to remove]

Comment: Hello.  Welcome to the site.  Can you give us your make/model/year.  Each brand of manufacturer uses different connector types that may have a different removal method from another manufacturers connector.  Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

First off, no, you do not need to disconnect anything else. If the key is NOT in the ignition, there is no electricity going through these connectors.

So, basically in the image below:

- Green Arrows: Pry up gently with a flat tip screwdriver to release these catches. Pull gently on the electrical cable as you do this to disconnect.
- Yellow Arrows: Screws, remove these to release the connectors.
- Red Arrows: Push these in and wiggle to remove the switches. You'll usually have two of these, one on each side to press on.

[image]

Comment: To complete this answer: "No, you do not need to disconnect anything else. If they key is NOT in the ignition, there is no electricity going through these connectors."

Comment: @tlhIngan - Thanks! I missed that ... must be tired.

Comment: @Paulster2: fixed it for ya. :)

Comment: While those wire harnesses are probably harmless without the key in the ignition, it is worth mentioning that as long as the battery is connected, _some_ circuits have power. For example, opening the door typically turns the dome lights on, key in the ignition or not.

Comment: @Snowman - Even so, there would be nothing in the door switches which would give me cause for concern.